# React-Redux component state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

tl;dr I'm trying to save initial state inside a sub-container component but it gets updated to the new values every time the Redux store gets updated. I probably missed something in configuration and I need help to sort things out.

index.tsx

```
const store = createStore(reducers, loadedState, enhancer);
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById(containerId)
)
```

AppProps.ts

```
function mapStateToProps(state: StoreState){
  return{
    ... // app props
    userDetails: state.userDetails // array of objects fetched by id
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch: ReactRedux.Dispatch<actions.AppActions>){
  return{
    ... // app methods
    detailsUpdate: (props: UpdateProps) => (dispatch(actions.detailsUpdate(props: UpdateProps)))
  }
}
ReactRedux.connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App)
```

Actions.ts

```
function detailsUpdate(props: UpdateProps): UpdateUserDetails {
    return {
        type: UPDATE_USER_DETAILS,
        props: { ... }
    }
}
```

Reducers.ts

```
export function reducers(state: StoreState, action: actions.AppActions): StoreState {    
    let newState: StoreState =  {...state};
    switch (action.type) {
        case actions.UPDATE_USER_DETAILS:
        ... // reducer code
        break;
        case actions.UPDATE_PRODUCTS:
        ... // reducer code
        break;
    return newState;
}
```

App.tsx

```
const App = (allProps: IAppProps, state: StoreState) => {
  <UserDetailsContainer
    id="generalDetails"
    userDetails={allProps.userDetails.byId}
    detailsUpdate={allProps.detailsUpdate}
  />
}
```

UserDetailsContainer.tsx <sup>1</sup>

```
class UserDetailsContainer extends
React.Component<UserDetailsContainerProps, UserDetailsState> {    
    constructor(props: UserDetailsContainerProps) {
        super(props);      
        this.state = {
            userData: props.userDetails[props.id]
        }
    }

    render(){
       <input type="text"
        value={this.props.userDetails[this.props.id].address}
      />
    }
}
```

detailsUpdate triggers UPDATE_USER_DETAILS action and reducer updates store state with new value. Now, UserDetailsContainer receives updated version of userDetails from the store which is fine for displaying new value in `<input type="text">` element.

However, this.state gets updated with new value which I expect shouldn't happen as constructor should be called only once (and is). This prevents me from referencing initial value in case I need it for reset or other.

Please ask for any missing information and/ or clarification and ignore any typos as the app works without errors otherwise.

1 Component usually renders another presentational component for `<input type="text">`which I omitted here for brevity.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using combine reducer ?

Comment: @Prabhu: I'm not using combineReducers but have different method for working with reducers. I updated the question with store creation and reducers.ts example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following only makes a shallow copy of state object.

```
let newState: StoreState =  {...state};
```

So if you assign

```
this.state = {
   userData: props.userDetails[props.id]
}
```

And then modify the array inside your reducer, you will also modify the component's state since it references the same object.
This also goes against the concept of redux - reducer should not mutate it's arguments.

Note that this exact mistake is highlighted in the redux docs: https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns#common-mistake-2-only-making-a-shallow-copy-of-one-level

Comment: Wow, thanks for pointing that out! I don't know how I missed it as all reducers inside reducers.ts are using nested update syntax. Now that I fixed it this.state is saved as expected and doesn't get updated with Redux state. Thanks! :)